# Storing array of elements in different rows of MYSQL from PHP is not working

Tags: php, arrays

Below is my JSON data, where the value has array of data.

```
{"products":"[31, 49, 48, 47]"}
```

I need to store different `products` in different rows of my sql database.

Below is the PHP code where I able to get only the value.

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
$product_ids =  $obj->{'products'};
```

The result of `$product_ids` is `[31, 49, 48, 47]`

Now I have to traverse through the array of values in `$product_ids`and store each value in different rows of MYSQL database.

To store the values in different rows of MYSQL I tried the below code.

```
for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($product_ids); $x++)
{
$row = $product_ids[$x];
$q = mysql_query("Insert into table_name(column_name) values ('$row') ");
}
```

But I am not able to achieve what I actually want. Above code stores only the square bracket([) inside MYSQL, I am not able to store the elements of the array.

I am very new to PHP. Any help would be really greatfull.

Thanks.

Comment: if  json was so `'{"products":[31, 49, 48, 47]}`; your code will be fine. Now $product_ids is string `[31, 49, 48, 47]`. You should remove brackets from the string an use explode() function. For example so `$product_ids =  explode(', ', trim($obj->{'products'}, '[]'));`

Comment: Yeah.. Removed the brackets using the following code $string_ids = str_replace(array('[',']'),array(' '),$product_ids);. But Only "3" is stored in database.

Comment: I rewrote my comment/ look now

Comment: the result is `$product_ids = 31494847`

Comment: https://eval.in/512452

Comment: @splash58 Thanks a lot. It is working .

Comment: You can post this as an answer. I will accpt it.

Comment: I was out of the comp. Now will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if json was so `{"products":[31, 49, 48, 47]}` your code will be fine. Now $product_ids is string `[31, 49, 48, 47]`. You should remove brackets from the string an use explode() function. For example so

```
$json = '{"products":"[31, 49, 48, 47]"}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
$product_ids = explode(', ', trim($obj->{'products'}, '[]'));
for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($product_ids); $x++)
{
$row = $product_ids[$x];
$q = mysql_query("Insert into table_name(column_name) values ('$row') ");
}
```

[Demo](http://eval.in/512452)

Answer (score 1):

While obtaining the JSON value, I suggest you drop the square brackets. If it's vital for you to have them in your JSON, remove them in your PHP code.

```
$product_ids = trim($product_ids, "[]");
```

Once removed, you can extract numbers in your string into an array:

```
$productIdArray = explode(",", $product_ids);
```

Now, in `$productIdArray` you will have your values:

```
Array (
    0 => "31",
    1 => "49",
    2 => "48",
    3 => "47"
)
```

And now you can iterate over this array in order to put the required values into your database.

```
foreach($productIdArray as $productId) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name(column_name) VALUES ('$productId') ");
}
```

Also please reconsider using `mysql_*`, it's deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$obj = '{"products":"[31, 49, 48, 47]"}';
$objArray = json_decode($obj,true);
$objArray = explode(',',trim($objArray['products'], "[]"));
foreach ($objArray as $key => $value){

   $q = mysql_query("Insert into table_name(column_name) values ('trim($value)') ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<?php

$json = '{"product":[31,49,48,47]}'; 
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
$product_ids= $obj['product'];
for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($product_ids); $x++)
{
$row = $product_ids[$x];
// $q = mysql_query("Insert into table_name(column_name) values ('$row') ");
}?>
```

work fine